# How to uninstall a python package installed using .tar.gz?

Tags: python, pip, pytest-bdd

I am new to python. I recently installed a package using the source file .tar.gz in my conda environment using `pip install <absolute_path_to_.tar_.gz_file>`. Upon trying to uninstall the package I am getting below error -

```
(3point7) wkmca9711659:~ ricagarw$ pip uninstall /Users/ricagarw/Downloads/allure-pytest-bdd-2.8.6b0.tar.gz
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to uninstall (see "pip help uninstall")
```

I am not using `requirements.txt` for my project. How should I uninstall the package ?

Comment: `pip uninstall <packagename>` should work

Answer (score 0):

> `pip uninstall allure-pytest` will uninstall the package.

Comment: If you do now the package name  precisely, you can list all packages via ```pip freeze```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the .tar.gz file you should find a setup.py file, inside this file you will find an structure similar to this:

```
setup(
    ...,
    name='packagename',
    ...,
)
```

So, using a pip uninstall with that 'packagename' you can uninstall it successfully

```
pip uninstall packagename
```